# How do edit all values in a timestamp column at once?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Good Day. I have a column "expdate" with timestamp values in this format Y-m-d (MariaDB). The data type is set to 'timestamp'.

I want to increase all the time values in this 'expdate' column by 1 day.

I've tried quite a number of syntax but I am just not getting it right.

```
UPDATE `gold10` SET `expdate`= Replace(expdate,date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Thank You.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: The column data type is set to Timestamp on phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date functions!

One method is just to add an interval:

```
UPDATE gold10
    SET expdate = expdate + interval 1 day;
```

You can also use `date_add()`, but I find interval arithmetic to be easier to follow.

Comment: sorry it took so long before marking this as my accepted answer. I was new then, so I didn't really understood how things went on around here then. But I think I'm getting to understand stack overflow better now..

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_ADD function of MySQL,just add the following query:

```
UPDATE `gold10` SET `expdate`= Replace(expdate,DATE_ADD(expdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this code on sql workspace in phpmyadmin. It returned

MySQL said: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1